# import tensorflow:DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

PS C:\Users\gu> python --version
Python 3.7.6
PS C:\Users\gu> pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
PS C:\Users\gu> pip install tensorflow
...
Successfully built absl-py termcolor
Successfully installed absl-py-0.9.0 astunparse-1.6.3 cachetools-4.1.1 gast-0.3.3 google-auth-1.19.2
...
import tensorflow as tf

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: DLL load failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     48 import numpy as np
     49 
---> 50 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     51 
     52 # Protocol buffers

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     67 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     68 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 69   raise ImportError(msg)
     70 
     71 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: DLL load failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

The installed version is : tensorflow-2.2.0
I tried to install it in a virtual environment, but it was the same result.
And the same error occurs even when Python and Anaconda are reinstalled. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to Visual Studios. Try installing Visual Studios 2015([from here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015)) and then install tensorflow.

Comment: Thank You for the response.but It is already installed.